# XHR finished loading [...] log message

Tags: google-chrome

I get a JavaScript console log message each time an Ajax request finishes loading; the issue is demonstrated in the attached screenshot.

[image]

I don't know how I activated this logging. How to deactivate it? I'm on ExtJS 4.1.

Comment: This question and answers also apply to the message `Fetch finished loading: ...`, as is in Chromium today (2021-10-14)

Answer (score 168, accepted):

It's not an extjs issue! You click on the gear icon in the right bottom corner and uncheck Log XMLHttpRequests.

### Chrome 111

Open the console, click settings (top right), uncheck "Log XMLHttpRequests"
[image]

### Chrome 55

Open the console, right click the open area, uncheck "Log XMLHttpRequests" OR click the vertical "..." in the top right, go to settings, and uncheck "Log XMLHttpRequests" under the "Console" header.

[image: chrome 55 screenshot 1]

[image: chrome 55 screenshot]

older screenshot:
[image: recent screenshot]

### Older Chrome

[image: older screenshot]

Comment: Does anyone know a trick / workaround on how to disable this in code? I mean so that you don't have to change any settings in Chrome?

Comment: It's a chrome feature. You're not allowed to change chrome settings via a web page. That would be a major security breach. I think by default the flag is unchecked anyway...

Answer (score 11):

The correct answer belongs to VDP, but I think is about a older Chrome so in my latest 
Chrome version is a little bit different the process to hide that requests...

1. Open the developer console
2. Click the console settings like shows the image

[image]

3. Then deactivate the option Log

[image]

4. Refresh the page
5. If is still showing the requests, deactivate some chrome extension of yours and refresh again.

Comment: You can also simply right click the console and "Log XMLHttpRequests" will be an option. Using Chrome Version 55.0.2883.87 (64-bit)

Answer (score 2):

**Selected context only img**

[image: Image 1]

For me it works using the check `Selected context only` in the `Customize and control DevTool`. Chrome Version 66.0.3359.181 (Build official) (64 bits)

Selected context only Image
[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 1):

[image]Inspect Element, under the sources you will find a blue icon. Click over this blue icon so that a marked line will be appeared over this icon. Your problem will be solved.

Comment: This does sound convenient, but I'm having trouble following you. By 'Inspect Element', do you mean that option in the right-click menu? Is this just your way of opening the Developer Console? By 'the sources', do you mean the Sources tab, or the Sources tree under that tab? The former has no blue icon; the latter has multiple blue icons. By 'click over', do you mean some widget above this blue icon? Maybe include a screenshot? If you can clarify all this, we can edit your answer and make it an upvote winner. ☺

Comment: Yes, exactly same meaning and that is source tab.

Comment: Is the blue icon you're talking about 'Deactivate Breakpoints'? It's the only one I see in your screen shot, and in my Chrome Developer Tools window, I still see XHR messages in the logs while it's deactivated. What does the tool tip say, when you hover over the blue icon you're talking about?

Comment: For me it was, right click on the logitem In the console.