# Why is chrome dev tools printing XHML status to console

Tags: google-chrome

I can't figure out why all of a sudden zone.js is printing to the browsers console. It seems to have started randomly, I didnt change any configurations and it is only happening in chrome. 
[image]

Comment: That has nothing to do with zone.js, check this answer to track the issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12840024/xhr-finished-loading-log-message

Comment: I had a feeling it was a chrome setting but couldn't find it! Thank you!