# hide xhttp requests from bowser console

Tags: javascript, php

I want to hide xhttp requests from the browser's console So.
What i have here is a ajax request repeating in certain intervals of time

```
setInterval(function(){
$.ajax({
type:'post'..
url:...
});
},20);
```

And when the code above executes, I have this in the browser's console

```
XHR finished loading: POST "https://fibble.tk/chats.php".
XHR finished loading: POST "https://fibble.tk/chats.php".
XHR finished loading: POST "https://fibble.tk/chats.php".
XHR finished loading: POST "https://fibble.tk/chats.php".
```

I tried to hide the following from the console by using the code below:

```
setInterval(function(){
console.clear();
},1);
```

For protection I want to hide these from the consoles and I don't think that i'm doing it the right way as when the script above is running , the console flashes again and again.


I'm looking for a better method for this
Any help is appreciated
**EDIT**
**To see it just copy the above code and open the console and do paste the code**

Comment: Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12840024/xhr-finished-loading-log-message

Comment: Is this a solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12840024/xhr-finished-loading-log-message

Comment: checked, that is to hide the request for a user, anyone can uncheck the option and view them again. I want to remove the logs for everyone

Comment: What kind of script needs an interval of 20ms???? And 1ms? Really?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XHR finished loading \[...\] log message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12840024/xhr-finished-loading-log-message)

Comment: @HyyanAboFakher that is to hide the request for a user, anyone can uncheck the option and view them again. I want to remove the logs for everyone

Comment: Javascript is easily modified from the client. Someone can easily remove the call to clear the console. [Security through obscurity is a terrible idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533965/why-is-security-through-obscurity-a-bad-idea), just some food for thought..

Comment: @kerbholz thought it will make the procedure smooth

Answer (score 3):

You cannot prevent the debug tools in the browser belonging to the user from telling the user what their browser is doing.

Comment: Okay but those requests are exposed to the user, relating with the server. Will it ever cause any response to leak? [Here see this](https://blog.versionone.com/spy-on-browser-http-requests/)

Comment: That article is based on a false premise — that the browser is something that does not belong the user. The user can't "spy" on their browser any more than a carpenter can spy on their saw. The browser is an extension of the user. The user is asking your website for stuff. The website is giving the user that stuff. The browser is just the tool the user uses. Nothing you tell the browser can be a secret from the user.

Comment: I didn't know it was based on a false premise. Okay I now know.