# Why do I get "Fetch failed loading" when it actually worked?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, post, fetch-api

I use the following code to POST the users position to my own backend-service via the Fetch API:

```
window.onload = () => {
    let getPosition = (options) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject, options);
        });
    };

    getPosition().then(pos => {
        const data = new FormData();
        data.append('latitude', String(pos.coords.latitude));
        data.append('longitude', String(pos.coords.longitude));

        fetch('/', {             // <--- error is thrown in this line
            method: 'POST',
            body: data
        }).then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw Error('Data sent - Network response NOT OK');
            } else {
                console.log('Data sent - Network response OK')
            }
        });
    });
};
```

This works flawlessly and the backend-service sends back a positive empty response. `Data sent - Network response OK` is logged in the browser's console and everything is fine except that immediately after, this is logged:

[image]

How come I get a `Fetch failed loading: POST` even though the POST succeeded, the response is OK and the status code in the Chrome network tab is `200 OK`? Is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I had the same behaviour that you were seeing. 
My server responded to the `POST` request with a `204` (Empty Response) and an empty (Content-Length=0) response. 
I tried changing that to just respond with a "ok" message instead (edit: actually just returning the created object now) and the `fetch` error log disappeared.

It seems to me that `fetch` (at least in Chrome) erroneously logs "Fetch Failed" when the response body is empty, even if the request was successful.

Comment: I added one character to the response body and it is now working.

Comment: If you are sending back an empty response use status code `204 EMPTY RESPONSE`. Can't test it right now, but maybe fetch won't log any error then.

Comment: @oemel09 I tried with the 204 now and it also outputs a "Failed" log

Comment: @rewolf @oemel09 I switched to using `204 EMPTY RESPONSE` with Express: `res.status(204).send({})`. Notably it does still require you to send along an empty object (`{}`). I still think that `204` is the correct choice here and I hope I can remove the exmpty object at some point.

Comment: @MiXT4PE @oemel09 I agree `204` is most appropriate! :) By definition, we shouldn't need to return an empty object `{}` for that status code.. so I think `fetch` has bad logic there.

Comment: I resolved a "Fetch failed loading" message by adding a 204 resp code to the server side response. Now Chrome logs a message of "Fetch finished loading". That seems a bit verbose to me. Then I found this, which describes how to turn off that logging: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12840024/xhr-finished-loading-log-message

Comment: returning 204 doesn't stop fetch failed loading for me with chrome 83.x, I resolved by returning a few characters with 200.

Comment: How is this the preferred response? Changing the server code because its not handled correctly on chrome hardly qualifies.

What does one do if they haven't developed the API?

Answer (score 11):

This happens because you don't read the empty response body. I noticed this, because Django triggers a `broken pipe` error on the server side. To fix this, just read the empty body out.

```
async function fetchSomething() {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST'
    })
    await response.text()
    return response.ok
}
```